# passing data to another component not working

Tags: angular

I am getting an undefined value when passing an object to another component in my application. Component 1 and 2 are unrelated and there is no shared service available to use.

**component 1**

```
this.transferData =
{
  accountNumber: this.accountNumber,
  availableBalance: this.tileData.account.available,
  balance: this.tileData.account.balance,
  accountName: this.tileData.account.name,
  accountType: this.tileData.account.accountType,
  productCode: '',
  accountNameAndNumber: this.tileData.account.name + ' | ' + this.tileData.account.number
}

<component2 [data]="transferData"></component2>
```

**component 2**

```
@Input() transferData: any;
console.log(transferData); --> undefined
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `data` not `transferData`:

```
@Input() data: any;
```

Please refer to the offical documentation: https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs

Answer (score 0):

use data.

```
@Input() data: any;
console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the **same property name** when binding data.

```js
@Input() data: any;
```

[Please refer the official documentation here..](https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs#sending-data-to-a-parent-component)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).